# How to process the records in Pandas to find the total time for 'true' and then 'false' and then again for 'true' for sorted data on particular day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Input Data format given like this.

| date | State |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 18 2021 7:26:9 PM UTC | True |
| Jan 18 2021 7:24:56 PM UTC | True |
| Jan 18 2021 7:23:42 PM UTC | True |
| Oct 27 2020 9:36:52 PM UTC | False |
| Oct 27 2020 8:23:16 PM UTC | False |
| Oct 27 2020 7:48:20 PM UTC | False |
| Oct 27 2021 6:24:56 PM UTC | True |
| Oct 27 2021 5:24:56 PM UTC | True |
| Oct 28 2020 7:48:20 PM UTC, False |  |

Output I am looking how many hours system was working and how many hour system was not working (false) in a day.

1. Output I am looking  on Jan 18, true is (7:26:9 - 7:23:42 = 2 mins
   27 sec)
2. On Jan 27 False is (9:36:52 - 7:48:20 =  1hour 48 min 32
   sec)
3. On Jan 27 true is (6:24:56 - 5:24:56 = 1 hour) How to use
   Pandas function here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: A day normally goes from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. What about the missing periods?

Comment: Question  has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `ml` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes and aggregate `min` and `max` by dates by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with helper column `g` for consecutive `True`s and `False`s, then subtract and get timedeltas.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['g'] = df['State'].ne(df['State'].shift()).cumsum()

df = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.date, 'State','g'], sort=False)['date'].agg(['max','min'])
df = df['max'].sub(df['min']).reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index(name='td')
print (df)
         date  State              td
0  2021-01-18   True 0 days 00:02:27
1  2020-10-27  False 0 days 01:48:32
2  2021-10-27   True 0 days 01:00:00
3  2020-10-28  False 0 days 00:00:00
```

And if need seconds add [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['sec'] = df['td'].dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
         date  State      td
0  2021-01-18   True   147.0
1  2020-10-27  False  6512.0
2  2021-10-27   True  3600.0
3  2020-10-28  False     0.0
```